# How to exclude Standard fields when reading an item's fields

Tags: field

When reading an item's fields like this:

```
item.Fields.ReadAll();
```

It reads all the fields. Is there a way to exclude the default Sitecore fields and get only the fields that a user has created.

For example, I have created a template with 2 fields - Title & Description.

```
for(Field field in item.Fields)
{

}
```

The above loop will run through all the fields of the item, but I want to get only the non-default fields.

This is for updating field values programmatically and the field IDs are not always known.

And there is a chance of updating the values of the Sitecore fields.

Is that possible.

Comment: What problem does this cause by reading all fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll say this

1. Users don't create fields, developers create fields
2. Issuing a `Field.ReadAll` is absolutely terrible for performance. Make sure you only do this in a script, never ever in runtime code.

That said, what you probably want is this.

```
        var i = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        var ownFieldCollection = i.Template.OwnFields;

        foreach (var field in ownFieldCollection)
        {
            string value = i.Fields[field.Key].Value;
            // or do whatever here
        }
```

This will get you a the fields defined directly on the template of the item you are processing.

Alternatively if you really do want fields, inherited fields, and whatnot - this is how to get to them.

```
        var i = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        var templateFieldsCollection = i.Template.Fields;

        foreach (var field in templateFieldsCollection)
        {
            if (!field.InnerItem.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith("/sitecore/templates/system", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                string value = i.Fields[field.Key].Value;
                // or do whatever here
            }
        }
```

Either way, the cache defying `.ReadAll` fields call is avoided.

No solution should need code like this however.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can skip reading all the fields that are part of the Standard Template, but you could filter them out.

**Example:** The following will get all fields on the Standard Template and remove from the list of fields on the Sample Item (and its base templates).

```
# Create a list of field names on the Standard Template. This will help us filter out extraneous fields.
$standardTemplate = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID ([Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::StandardTemplate.ToString())
$standardTemplateTemplateItem = [Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem]$standardTemplate
[string[]]$standardFields = $standardTemplateTemplateItem.OwnFields + $standardTemplateTemplateItem.Fields | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key -Unique

$sampleItemTemplate = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
$sampleItemTemplateTemplateItem = [Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem]$sampleItemTemplate
[string[]]$sampleItemFields = $sampleItemTemplateTemplateItem.OwnFields + $sampleItemTemplateTemplateItem.Fields | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key -Unique

[Linq.Enumerable]::Except($sampleItemFields, $standardFields)

title
text
```

Comment: I'm doing it in C#. Yes, filtering them works for me. Read all the fields of `Standard Template` and filter them. Is that correct. Could you pls provide a littl emore explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Are you reading the fields of `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Standard template` or `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template`

Comment: The ID used is for Standard Template and Sample Item